# Do you need a separately cloned git repo for each bot on a single xcode project

Tags: xcode, git, clone, bots, xcode-server

I am using Xcode Server bots.  I have a number of bots setup for a single project.  I noticed you need to setup the git repo details for each individual bot and this must be cloned for each bot.

Is it possible to just clone the git repo once and share that code across multiple bots for a single project?